# Javascript Split() not working same way as explicit array declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

Could anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong:

I want the list of YouTube video IDs in my `#videoslist` DIV to be split into and populate an array used by a simple video carousel I found.

When the array of video IDs is explicitly declared in the script, it works fine, but if I take the `.text()` or `.html()` `(jQuery)` of the DIV and split that into an array, even though the array gets populated fine, there seems to be a problem somewhere that means it doesn't work, but I can't figure it out...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PYMBB/

Comment: maybe you need to trim values of your array before using them into the carrousel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there are spaces after the semicolons. You can either remove the spaces after the semicolons in your DIV or trim the strings before adding them to the YouTube code.

Comment: I made a modification  to your Fiddle and it seems to work by removing those spaces: http://jsfiddle.net/PYMBB/1/

Comment: Thanks so much! So embarrassing... :)
I changed the .split(";") to .split("; ");